# Formatting sentence in Python to be in italic

Tags: python

I am trying to format some text that I am trying to add to a python script. It has two sentences and I would like to have the second sentence to be in italic.

Given below is the sentence:

```
'Key points include' + '\n' + 'Improved performance'
```

I would like to have the phrase *Improved performance* to be in  italic

Expected Output:

Key points include
*Improved performance*

Comment: @AhsanulHaque I have tried that but that dint work

Comment: The suggested answer works only if your console supports italics. If it does not, than what you want is not possible.

Comment: https://indianpythonista.wordpress.com/2017/04/02/formatted-text-in-linux-terminal-using-python/

Comment: The `\e[3m` escape sequence formats text as italic in shells and terminals that support it, but some build systems (like pycharm or sublimeREPL) don't support italics